# Html table is hiding in the sidebar

Tags: html, css

I have created a html table. The content of [2 columns](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kz8Cj.png), in the table are hiding in the sidebar, and on mobile, data of [only few columns are shows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sRCa6.png). Instead of hiding content in the sidebar, I want to display it. I want to add scroll in the bottom.  If there is any other way to fix the error, please do let me know.

```css
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    width: 100%;
  }
  table td{border: 1px solid black;
    color: black;}
  th, td {
    text-align: left;
    padding: 8px;
  }
  
  th {
    background-color: #4CAF50;
    color: white;
  }
  
  tr:nth-child(even) {
    background-color: #f2f2f2;
  }
  
  tbody {
    height: 200px;
    overflow-y: scroll;
  }
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
<tr>
    <td>Date</td>
    <td>Day</td>
    <td>Time From</td>
    <td>Time To</td>
    <td>%</td>
    <td>Sunday</td>
    <td>Monday</td>
    <td>Tuesday</td>
    <td>Wednesday</td>
    <td>Thursday</td>
    <td>Friday 1</td>
    <td>Saturday</td>
    <td>Hse</td>
</tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>06-04-23</td>
      <td>Thursday</td>
      <td>7:04</td>
      <td>8:39</td>
      <td>76%</td>
      <td>Mon</td>
      <td>Monday</td>
      <td>Monday</td>
      <td>Monday</td>
      <td>Monday</td>
      <td>Monday</td>
      <td>6</td>
      <td>6</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>06-04-23</td>
      <td>Thursday</td>
      <td>7:04</td>
      <td>8:39</td>
      <td>76%</td>
      <td>Mon</td>
      <td>Monday</td>
      <td>Monday</td>
      <td>Monday</td>
      <td>Monday</td>
      <td>Monday</td>
      <td>6</td>
      <td>6</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I understand what you want to do completely but if you want a scrollbar to appear under the table on smaller screen, just wrap your table into a container (div or section, any will do), then set the container's `width` to `100%` and `overflow-x` to `auto`.

Now the container is always fit to screen, what `overflow-x` do is when the content width of the container become bigger than the width of the container, it spawns a scrollbar under the container.

I modified your code to achieve what you want. Have a look.

```css
.table-wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  overflow-x: auto;
}

table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    width: 100%;
  }
  table td{border: 1px solid black;
    color: black;}
  th, td {
    text-align: left;
    padding: 8px;
  }
  
  th {
    background-color: #4CAF50;
    color: white;
  }
  
  tr:nth-child(even) {
    background-color: #f2f2f2;
  }
  
  tbody {
    height: 200px;
    overflow-y: scroll;
  }
```

```html
<div class="table-wrapper">
  <table>
    <thead>
  <tr>
      <td>Date</td>
      <td>Day</td>
      <td>Time From</td>
      <td>Time To</td>
      <td>%</td>
      <td>Sunday</td>
      <td>Monday</td>
      <td>Tuesday</td>
      <td>Wednesday</td>
      <td>Thursday</td>
      <td>Friday 1</td>
      <td>Saturday</td>
      <td>Hse</td>
  </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>06-04-23</td>
        <td>Thursday</td>
        <td>7:04</td>
        <td>8:39</td>
        <td>76%</td>
        <td>Mon</td>
        <td>Monday</td>
        <td>Monday</td>
        <td>Monday</td>
        <td>Monday</td>
        <td>Monday</td>
        <td>6</td>
        <td>6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>06-04-23</td>
        <td>Thursday</td>
        <td>7:04</td>
        <td>8:39</td>
        <td>76%</td>
        <td>Mon</td>
        <td>Monday</td>
        <td>Monday</td>
        <td>Monday</td>
        <td>Monday</td>
        <td>Monday</td>
        <td>6</td>
        <td>6</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks. It works. One more request. Can the width of first column (date column data)be increased too? https://i.imgur.com/HK5oYv3.png